# Rearranging attributes in Modelio

Tags: modelio

Perhaps a dumb question but it has me stumped: How does one rearrange/sort attributes and operations in Modelio?

I'm using Version 5.3.01 on Windows 11.

Say I create a class and add three attributes:
attr_1 : String
attr_2 : String
attr_3 : String

But later I decide that I want attr_1 to be last in the last, so that my class now shows:
attr_2 : String
attr_3 : String
attr_1 : String

How do I achieve this? Surely this shouldn't be difficult?

All I can find in the manual is the "Handling Diagram Elements" entry which suggests dragging and dropping should work. I've tried drag and drop with left mouse, middle mouse, ctrl, alt, ctrl+alt, shift, etc. all to no avail.

In the Element view on the left, I *can* update the order under the class header (using "Move Selected Element Up/Down) but it isn't replicated on my diagrams.

Comment: There is a closed Github issue https://github.com/ModelioOpenSource/Modelio/issues/77 that suggests to set the _Automatic content_ property of the class to _Manual_, and then the diagram should update when you rearrange the classes in the Element view. However, I tried that out and it does not seem to work (i.e., the elements in the Element view are moved but the diagram doesn't update).

Comment: What _did_ work though is the approach described in https://github.com/ModelioOpenSource/Modelio/issues/56, i.e., remove (mask) the items from the diagram and re-add them.

Comment: Same worked for me. I noticed that in the first link the window title in the gif is Modelio 5.4. Perhaps this is something that has been added

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a different class model, move the functions or atributes to the other model and move them back in the order you want them in the original model. It is a bit convoluted but it works.
If someone has a better alternative though, I'm all ears!